# Sketch phase portray of $ x'' + 3x^2 + - 3 = 0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am sketching the phase portray of $ x'' + 3x^2 + - 3 = 0 $. 
First of all I found the corresponding ODE system:

\begin{align*}
  x' = y \\
  y' = -3x^2 + 3
\end{align*}

The critical points are (-1,0) and (1,0). However I am going to center it in the origin so I will ignore the +3, the solution is the same anyway.

I tried to use the method of linearization but I an eigenvalue of real part equals to 0 and this does not give information.

Then I tried using Liaupnov method, so I need to find a function $V(x,y)$ such that $V(0,0)=0$, $V(x,y) \geq 0$ and $V'(x,y) \leq 0$, this would mean that the origin is stable. However I am struggling to find such a function here. Any hints?

Comment: **None** of the objects/tools you mention is needed to draw a phase portrait.  One only needs to know the signs of $x'$ and $y'$, depending on the point $(x,y)$. In your case, this is direct, no?

Comment: @Did Yes you are right I was totally overthinking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the Jacobian at the critical points ${\bf x}^*$

$$
J({\bf x}^*) = \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ -6x^* & 0}
$$

with eigenvalues $\lambda^2 = -6x^*$. That means that for

> ${\bf x}_1^* = (+1,0)$ the eigenvalues are $\lambda_1^{\pm} = \pm i \sqrt{6}$

Solution is a cycle

> ${\bf x}_2^* = (1,0)$ the eigenvalues are $\lambda_2^{\pm} = \pm \sqrt{6}$

Solution is a saddle point. You can find the directions of the stable and unstable manifolds by calculating the eigenvectors. I will leave that part to you

Here's a sketch

[image]

Comment: "Solution is a cycle" Not necessarily. Even if the eigenvalues of the Jacobian are purely complex, the solutions of the (original, non linearized) system need not be cycles.

Comment: @Did Thanks for the comment. I have, repeatedly, seen this type of clarifications form you. Are there any conditions for this to work at all? Because If I see the solutions, I can see them going around $(1, 0)$. Or should I abandon this for good? Thanks

Comment: The Jacobian of a system $x'=f(x,y)$, $y'=g(x,y)$, near its fixed point $(0,0)$ describes $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$, but only **at order $1$**. A canonical example might be the system $$x'=-y\qquad y'=x$$ with a fixed point at $(0,0)$ and a Jacobian matrix with eigenvalues $\pm i$, indicating a **center**, and whose solutions indeed are the circles $$x^2+y^2=x_0^2+y_0^2$$ But consider its perturbation $$x'=-y+cx^3\qquad y'=x+cy^3$$ for some fixed $c\ne0$. The Jacobian matrix at $(0,0)$ stays the same, again with eigenvalues $\pm i$, but, ...

Comment: ... by an elementary computation, $$(x^2+y^2)'=2c(x^4+y^4)$$ Thus, for every $c\ne0$, the solutions are not cycles anymore. Actually, for every $c<0$, $(0,0)$ is now a **stable focus** and the solutions are inwards spirals while, for every $c>0$, $(0,0)$ becomes an **unstable focus** and the solutions are outwards spirals.

Comment: But here you have a first integral $C=\frac12 x'^2+x^3x-3x$ so that all solutions lie on level curves, and thus solutions on bounded components of the level sets are periodic.